# Office JS - Excel, Add pivot chart

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins, pivot-chart

How can I add a PivotChart with office.js?

I can see the *pivotOptions* property for chart (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chart?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-chart-pivotoptions-member)
but I couldn't find a clear example of Pivot-Chart creation similar to the other docs pages (i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-pivottables)

Is it possible? Can you please show how?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    // Get the active worksheet
    var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Define the data range for the PivotTable
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:C10");
    // Create a PivotTable based on the data range
    var pivotTable = sheet.pivotTables.add("A15", dataRange, true);
    // Define the data range for the PivotChart
    var chartRange = sheet.getRange("E1:F10");
    // Create a PivotChart based on the PivotTable and data range
    var pivotChart = sheet.charts.add("A30", Excel.ChartType.columnClustered, pivotTable);
    pivotChart.setSourceData(chartRange);
    // Synchronize the changes with the workbook
    return context.sync();
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and Jinghui's answer is not working.
What is working is

```
    const dataAddress = "C2:D10"; // where your data is stored
    const pivotTableAddress = "A2"; // where you want your pivot to be created
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    const pivotTable = sheet.pivotTables.add(
        'Pivot Table name',
        dataAddress,
        pivotTableAddress
    );
    
    // in my case, i want asset as row & amountInMyCurrency as data
    pivotTable.rowHierarchies.add(pivotTable.hierarchies.getItem('asset'));
    pivotTable.dataHierarchies.add(
        pivotTable.hierarchies.getItem('amountInMyCurrency')
    );
    await sheet.context.sync();
      
    // then we add the chart like any other chart, Excel somehow pickup the pivotTable with just adding any cell of this pivot table
    const pivotChart = sheet.charts.add(
      Excel.ChartType.columnClustered,
      sheet.getRange(pivotTableAddress)
    );
    await sheet.context.sync();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**